# Can't access Postgres DB on Heroku app

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask, heroku-postgres

I have a Python 2.7 / Flask app running on Heroku that scrapes data and I now want to store that information in a database.

I've tried to follow tutorials [like this one](http://blog.y3xz.com/blog/2012/08/16/flask-and-postgresql-on-heroku) and apply this to my case but I can't get it to work.
  I have created & promoted my postgres database successfully on heroku.

I am fairly new to the Python project architecture and I suspect a simple problem in my setup.

## Here is my project structure

```
/myapplication
    Procfile
    run.py
    requirements.txt
    /app
        __init__.py
        mechanize_boilerplate.py
        views.py
        /static
        /templates
```

## Here is my **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
# DB Configuration
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('postgres://{link I got from heroku}')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from app import views
```

## Here is a portion of my views.py

```
from app import app
import mechanize_boilerplate
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name %r>' % self.name

@app.route('/db')
def dbtest():
    try:
        user = User('John', 'Foo@bar.com')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        print 'DB error'
    return 'done'
```

Basically when I visit myapp/db I want to create one record with id, name and email (john, foo@bar.com).

Any thoughts?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just prints 'DB error' which means the try failed. If I remove the 'try:' I get a 500 error.

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: I'm not sure, how should I print the exception?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')`

Answer (score 2):

replace this to log error message:

```
@app.route('/db')
def dbtest():
try:
    user = User('John', 'Foo@bar.com')
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    f = open('/tmp/error.log', 'w')
    f.write(e.message)
    f.close()
return 'done'
```

post your error message.

Comment: Thanks! I printed e.message and got: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'`

Comment: check your configuration with [configured Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution not mentionned is to use dj_database_url

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```